# How to check if a link field uses <nolink> in template

Tags: 8, theming

- I have a Custom Block type.
- It has a link field that allows `<nolink>`
- In the twig template for that Custom Block type I want to check if the link field has `<nolink>`.

I can see there is a protected value under #url for routeName that is NULL when there is a link, and `<nolink>` when `<nolink>` is used, but I can't figure out how to check it.

I can also see there's a protected uri under #url with a similar situation. If `<nolink>` is used, that value is NULL. If there is a link, the link is in there.

Comment: Have you already installed the Devel sub-module Kint and then put `{{ kint() }}` in your template to inspect the available methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your link field only allows 1 value.

```
{% if content.field_link.0['#url'].toString() is empty %} # or use "is not empty" if you're checking if there is a url. 
    # your code goes here
{% endif %}
```

If your field allows multiple link values then loop:

```
{% for link in content.field_link %}
  {% if link['#url'].toString() is empty %} # or use "is not empty" if you're checking if there is a url. 
    # your code goes here
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!

Comment: @SarahC I think you accidentally down-voted the answer :p

Comment: I did! I had to wait a certain amount of time to fix my vote! I felt terrible. I have fixed it. :)